# Selecting values from XML on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes, xquery

I have been trying to parse the following XML to extract values of STATNAME &
STATDIRECT
in SQL Server

```
set @xml= '
<ENVELOPE>
    <STATNAME>ABC</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>2</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED></STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
    <STATNAME>XYZ</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>10</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED>2</STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
    <STATNAME>LMN</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>20</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED>2</STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Using XML nodes to extract the values

```
SELECT
    t.v.value('(STATNAME/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS VOUCHERTYPE
    , i.p.value('(STATDIRECT/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS VCOUNT
FROM @XML.nodes('/ENVELOPE') AS t(v) 
CROSS APPLY @XML.nodes('/ENVELOPE/STATVALUE') AS i(p)
```

But this only repeats the first value of the XML instead of iterating to next row

Output

```
VOUCHERTYPE   VCOUNT
ABC           2
ABC           2
ABC           2
```

Expected output

```
VOUCHERTYPE   VCOUNT
ABC           2
XYZ           10
LMN           20
```

Comment: What platform are you using?  SQL Server?

Comment: Yes SQL server 
edited in question

Comment: A trick you can do is use `.` to see what is in a location to make sure your xquery is acting on what you expect.  So add the these two lines to your query and see what you get `t.v.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') as V_xml, i.p.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS i_xml`

Comment: this concats all the values together for V_xml column `ABCXYZLMN`

Comment: for a moderate number of nodes : `… from @XML.nodes('/ENVELOPE/STATNAME') AS t(v) 
cross apply (values(t.v.query('let $v := . return ../STATVALUE[. >> $v][1]'))) as i(p)`

Comment: @lptr thanks man this works but it also gets the STATSCANCELLED tag  along with the STATSVALUE tag
can you share some references to understand that query part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is using **Node Order Comparison Operator** ">>"

Check it out here: [Node Order Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/comparison-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver16#node-order-comparison-operators)

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<ENVELOPE>
    <STATNAME>ABC</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>2</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED></STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
    <STATNAME>XYZ</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>10</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED>2</STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
    <STATNAME>LMN</STATNAME>
    <STATVALUE>
        <STATDIRECT>20</STATDIRECT>
        <STATCANCELLED>2</STATCANCELLED>
    </STATVALUE>
</ENVELOPE>';

SELECT c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS VOUCHERTYPE
    , c.value('let $i := . return (/ENVELOPE/STATVALUE/STATDIRECT[. >> $i]/text())[1]', 'INT') AS VCOUNT
FROM @xml.nodes('/ENVELOPE/STATNAME') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| VOUCHERTYPE | VCOUNT |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 |
| XYZ | 10 |
| LMN | 20 |

Comment: Thanks this works but incase there is any STATDIRECT value empty it pulls the next value of the same can we manage to handle that?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Desired output based on the #1 above. Please edit your original question and provide it.